# SwiftUI dismiss View in UIHostingController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view that is shown using a `UIHostingController`. In a `navigationBar` I have an `X` button to close. What is the best approach to do it? I have seen some workarounds like `var dismissAction: (() -> Void)` and `self.dismiss` once you present the view.

I tried also `@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss` but it looks like iOS 15 only and for some reason did not work out for me.

Is there any elegant solution nowadays?

Comment: `\.dismiss` will only work for a SwiftUI view, not a UIKit view like `UIHostingController`, so I'm not surprised that didn't work. Your first approach is likely what you should do.

Comment: if you push it as UIKit controller then you should dismiss it as UIKit controller

Comment: thanks for the answers. Will dismiss it form the UIKit controller.